# boot_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_59.dll is missing

Tags: cgal

I am currently trying to install CGAL on Windows 10.

I have a problem when I try to open the file.exe of the example convex-hull2 generated using CMAKE-GUI and Visual C++ 2010 express: boot_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_59.dll is missing.

Here I specify all my installation steps followed from cgal.org/download/windows.html and http://acg.cs.tau.ac.il/cgal-at-tau/installing-cgal-and-related-programs-on-windows (because in a first try with only the documentation of cgal.org there were errors relative to the installation of Boost in Cmake-gui, errors solved with this method), it is quite long but I want to be exhaustive. Furthermore, some of the output of visual studio are in french but I put the traduction of the word in bracket.

I use Visual Studio 2010 (32-bits) and Visual C++ 2010 express.

**Installation of Boost:**

Download: boost_1_59_0-msvc-10.0-32.exe 
Execution of file.exe as an administrator; install in folder C:\dev\boost_1_59_0 
Installation ran well.
Here I added a step found on http://acg.cs.tau.ac.il/cgal-at-tau/installing-cgal-and-related-programs-on-windows since the CMAKE-GUI had Boost-related errors during the creation of the solution for CGAL.
I ran cd c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin then vcvars32.bat in the CMD to set the compiler to Visual studio 2010.
I ran:  pushd C:\ Then: cd C:\dev\boost_1_59_0 to go to the boost directory.
Then I ran: .\bootstrap

Then I ran: .\b2 link=static,shared threading=single,multi variant=debug,release
No errors reported (time of about 2 hours):
 “the Boost C++ libraries were successfully built!
   The following directory should be added to complier include paths:
   C:\dev\boost_1_59_0
   The following directory should be added to linker library paths:
   C:\dev\boost_1_59_0\stage\lib
   ”
I added :
BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=C:\dev\boost_1_59_0\lib32-msvc-10.0
BOOST_INCLUDEDIR=C:\dev\boost_1_59_0
C:\dev\boost_1_59_0 to the path

Installation of QT5
I downloaded qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2010-5.5.1.exe
I installed it in C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1
I added
I added QTDIR=C:\Qt\Gt5.5.1
              C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2010\bin to the path and I put it in the first place of the path as suggested in CGAL.org.

Installation of libQGLViewer:

I extracted the archive libQGLViewer-2.6.3 in C:\dev\libQGLViewer-2.6.3
I start the visual studio 2010 command prompt.
I put vcvars32.bat
I put pushd C:\dev\libQGLViewer-2.6.3\QGLViewer
I put qmake.exe and nmake.
No error message.

I added C:\dev\libQGLViewer-2.6.3\QGLViewer\release and C:\dev\libQGLViewer-2.6.3\QGLViewer\debug to my path.
I added QGLVIEWERROOT =C:\dev\libQGLViewer-2.6.3

Installation of CGAL:

I downloaded CGAL-4.7-Setup.exe from cgal.org.
I installed (as an administrator) it in 32-bits for all users and allowed it to install C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\auxilliary\gmp\lib to the path.
However, I had a pop-up that said that my path seems empty and I have do it manually.
So I added C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\auxiliary\gmp\lib to my path.

Then, I executed CMAKE-GUI as an administrator. I setted C:/dev/CGAL-4.7 for the location of source code; C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build for the location of the build.
Then, I clicked on configure. CMAKE-GUI asked me if it has the permission to create the new folder build. I said yes. I specified the generator Visual studio 10 2010 and “use defaut native compilers”.

```css
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.40219.1
The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.40219.1
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010 -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010 -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
== Setting paths ==
Build CGAL from release in directory CGAL-4.7
Packagenames: CGAL-4.7
== Setting paths (DONE) ==
== Generate version files ==
CGAL_MAJOR_VERSION=4
CGAL_MINOR_VERSION=7
CGAL_BUGFIX_VERSION=0
CGAL_SONAME_VERSION=11
CGAL_SOVERSION =11.0.1
CGAL_REFERENCE_CACHE_DIR=
Building shared libraries
Targetting Visual Studio 10 2010
Target build enviroment supports auto-linking
Using VC10 compiler.
Generator uses intermediate configuration directory: $(Configuration)
USING CMake version: 3.3.2
System: Windows
== Generate version files (DONE) ==
== Set up flags ==
Build type: Release
USING CXXFLAGS = ' /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /fp:strict /fp:except- /wd4503 /bigobj /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG'
USING LDFLAGS = ' /machine:X86 /INCREMENTAL:NO'
== Set up flags (DONE) ==
== Detect external libraries ==
External libraries supported: GMP;MPFR;ZLIB;OpenGL;LEDA;MPFI;RS;RS3;OpenNL;Eigen3;BLAS;LAPACK;QGLViewer;ESBTL;Coin3D;NTL;IPE
Preconfiguring library: GMP ...
Found GMP: C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libgmp-10.lib 
GMP has been preconfigured:
UseGMP-file: 
GMP include: C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/auxiliary/gmp/include
GMP libraries: C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libgmp-10.lib
GMP definitions: 
USING GMP_VERSION = '5.0.1'
Preconfiguring library: MPFR ...
Found MPFR: C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libmpfr-4.lib 
MPFR has been preconfigured:
UseMPFR-file: 
MPFR include: C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/auxiliary/gmp/include
MPFR libraries: C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libmpfr-4.lib
MPFR definitions: 
USING MPFR_VERSION = '3.0.0'
Boost version: 1.59.0
Found the following Boost libraries:
thread
system
Boost include: C:/dev/boost_1_59_0
Boost libraries: optimized;C:/dev/boost_1_59_0/lib32-msvc-10.0/boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_59.lib;debug;C:/dev/boost_1_59_0/lib32-msvc-10.0/boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_59.lib;optimized;C:/dev/boost_1_59_0/lib32-msvc-10.0/boost_system-vc100-mt-1_59.lib;debug;C:/dev/boost_1_59_0/lib32-msvc-10.0/boost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_59.lib
Boost definitions: 
USING BOOST_VERSION = '1.59.0'
== Detect external libraries (DONE) ==
== Write compiler_config.h ==
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_BOOST_VARIANT_SWAP_BUG - Failed
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_DENORMALS_COMPILE_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_FPU_ROUNDING_MODE_UNWINDING_VC_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_IEEE_754_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_ISTREAM_INT_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_5 - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_6 - Failed
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_7 - Failed
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_8 - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NESTED_CLASS_FRIEND_DECLARATION_BUG - Failed
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_LIMITS - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_NEXTAFTER - Failed
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_STL - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_WARNING_CPP_DIRECTIVE_BUG - Failed
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NUMERIC_LIMITS_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_OUTOFLINE_MEMBER_DEFINITION_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_TEMPLATE_IN_DEFAULT_PARAMETER_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_TYPENAME_BEFORE_DEFAULT_ARGUMENT_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_USING_BASE_MEMBER_BUG_2 - Success
== Write compiler_config.h (DONE) ==
== Generating build files ==
Configuring libCGAL
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL is configured
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Core' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Core
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_Core is configured
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_ImageIO' detected
Configuring libCGAL_ImageIO
Found OpenGL: opengl32 
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) 
OpenGL include: 
OpenGL libraries: glu32;opengl32
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_ImageIO is configured
NOTICE: libCGAL_ImageIO needs ZLib to read compressed files. That feature will not be activated.
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Qt3' detected
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Qt5' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Qt5
USING Qt5_VERSION = '5.5.1'
OpenGL include: 
OpenGL libraries: glu32;opengl32
OpenGL definitions: 
Qt5Core include: C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/5.5/msvc2010/include/;C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/5.5/msvc2010/include/QtCore;C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/5.5/msvc2010/.//mkspecs/win32-msvc2010
Qt5 libraries: Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Svg Qt5::OpenGL
Qt5Core definitions: -DQT_CORE_LIB
moc executable: C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/5.5/msvc2010/bin/moc.exe
uic executable: C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/5.5/msvc2010/bin/uic.exe
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_Qt5 is configured
Sources for CGAL component libraries 'CGAL_Core;CGAL_ImageIO;CGAL_Qt3;CGAL_Qt5' detected
== Generating build files (DONE) ==
Configuring done
```

I clicked again on configure since I had red entries.

```css
== Setting paths ==
Build CGAL from release in directory CGAL-4.7
Packagenames: CGAL-4.7
== Setting paths (DONE) ==
== Generate version files ==
CGAL_MAJOR_VERSION=4
CGAL_MINOR_VERSION=7
CGAL_BUGFIX_VERSION=0
CGAL_SONAME_VERSION=11
CGAL_SOVERSION =11.0.1
CGAL_REFERENCE_CACHE_DIR=
Building shared libraries
Targetting Visual Studio 10 2010
Target build enviroment supports auto-linking
Using VC10 compiler.
Generator uses intermediate configuration directory: $(Configuration)
USING CMake version: 3.3.2
System: Windows
== Generate version files (DONE) ==
== Set up flags ==
Build type: Release
USING CXXFLAGS = ' /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /fp:strict /fp:except- /wd4503 /bigobj /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG'
USING LDFLAGS = ' /machine:X86 /INCREMENTAL:NO'
== Set up flags (DONE) ==
== Detect external libraries ==
External libraries supported: GMP;MPFR;ZLIB;OpenGL;LEDA;MPFI;RS;RS3;OpenNL;Eigen3;BLAS;LAPACK;QGLViewer;ESBTL;Coin3D;NTL;IPE
Preconfiguring library: GMP ...
GMP has been preconfigured:
UseGMP-file: 
GMP include: C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/auxiliary/gmp/include
GMP libraries: C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libgmp-10.lib
GMP definitions: 
USING GMP_VERSION = '5.0.1'
Preconfiguring library: MPFR ...
MPFR has been preconfigured:
UseMPFR-file: 
MPFR include: C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/auxiliary/gmp/include
MPFR libraries: C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libmpfr-4.lib
MPFR definitions: 
USING MPFR_VERSION = '3.0.0'
Boost version: 1.59.0
Found the following Boost libraries:
thread
system
Boost include: C:/dev/boost_1_59_0
Boost libraries: optimized;C:/dev/boost_1_59_0/lib32-msvc-10.0/boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_59.lib;debug;C:/dev/boost_1_59_0/lib32-msvc-10.0/boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_59.lib;optimized;C:/dev/boost_1_59_0/lib32-msvc-10.0/boost_system-vc100-mt-1_59.lib;debug;C:/dev/boost_1_59_0/lib32-msvc-10.0/boost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_59.lib
Boost definitions: 
USING BOOST_VERSION = '1.59.0'
== Detect external libraries (DONE) ==
== Write compiler_config.h ==
== Write compiler_config.h (DONE) ==
== Generating build files ==
Configuring libCGAL
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL is configured
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Core' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Core
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_Core is configured
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_ImageIO' detected
Configuring libCGAL_ImageIO
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) 
OpenGL include: 
OpenGL libraries: glu32;opengl32
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_ImageIO is configured
NOTICE: libCGAL_ImageIO needs ZLib to read compressed files. That feature will not be activated.
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Qt3' detected
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Qt5' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Qt5
USING Qt5_VERSION = '5.5.1'
OpenGL include: 
OpenGL libraries: glu32;opengl32
OpenGL definitions: 
Qt5Core include: C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/5.5/msvc2010/include/;C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/5.5/msvc2010/include/QtCore;C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/5.5/msvc2010/.//mkspecs/win32-msvc2010
Qt5 libraries: Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Svg Qt5::OpenGL
Qt5Core definitions: -DQT_CORE_LIB
moc executable: C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/5.5/msvc2010/bin/moc.exe
uic executable: C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/5.5/msvc2010/bin/uic.exe
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_Qt5 is configured
Sources for CGAL component libraries 'CGAL_Core;CGAL_ImageIO;CGAL_Qt3;CGAL_Qt5' detected
== Generating build files (DONE) ==
Configuring done
```

Then I clicked on generate: generating done.

I opened the solution in Visual c++ 2010 express.

I generate ALL_BUILD in debug.

```css
1>------ Début de la génération (beginning of the generation) : Projet : ZERO_CHECK, Configuration : Debug Win32 ------
1>  Checking Build System
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/src/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/src/CGAL/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/src/CGAL_Core/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/src/CGAL_ImageIO/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/src/CGAL_Qt5/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
2>------ Début de la génération : Projet : CGAL, Configuration : Debug Win32 ------
2>  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/src/CGAL/CMakeLists.txt
2>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\src\CGAL\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
2>  all_files.cpp
2>     Création de la bibliothèque C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Debug/CGAL-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.lib et de l'objet C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Debug/CGAL-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.exp
2>     Création de la bibliothèque C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Debug/CGAL-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.lib et de l'objet C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Debug/CGAL-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.exp
2>  CGAL.vcxproj -> C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\bin\Debug\CGAL-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.dll
2>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
2>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
2>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
3>------ Début de la génération : Projet : CGAL_Core, Configuration : Debug Win32 ------
4>------ Début de la génération : Projet : CGAL_ImageIO, Configuration : Debug Win32 ------
5>------ Début de la génération : Projet : CGAL_Qt5, Configuration : Debug Win32 ------
3>  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/src/CGAL_Core/CMakeLists.txt
3>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\src\CGAL_Core\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
3>  all_files.cpp
4>  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/src/CGAL_ImageIO/CMakeLists.txt
4>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\src\CGAL_ImageIO\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
4>  all_files.cpp
5>  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/src/CGAL_Qt5/CMakeLists.txt
5>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\src\CGAL_Qt5\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
5>  Generating __/__/include/CGAL/Qt/moc_GraphicsViewNavigation.cpp
5>  Generating __/__/include/CGAL/Qt/moc_DemosMainWindow.cpp
5>  Generating __/__/include/CGAL/Qt/moc_GraphicsItem.cpp
5>  Generating __/__/include/CGAL/Qt/moc_GraphicsViewInput.cpp
5>  Generating qrc_CGAL.cpp
5>  Generating qrc_Input.cpp
5>  Generating qrc_File.cpp
5>  Generating qrc_Triangulation_2.cpp
5>  all_files.cpp
3>     Création de la bibliothèque C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Debug/CGAL_Core-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.lib et de l'objet C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Debug/CGAL_Core-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.exp
3>     Création de la bibliothèque C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Debug/CGAL_Core-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.lib et de l'objet C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Debug/CGAL_Core-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.exp
3>  CGAL_Core.vcxproj -> C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\bin\Debug\CGAL_Core-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.dll
3>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
3>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
3>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
4>     Création de la bibliothèque C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Debug/CGAL_ImageIO-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.lib et de l'objet C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Debug/CGAL_ImageIO-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.exp
4>     Création de la bibliothèque C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Debug/CGAL_ImageIO-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.lib et de l'objet C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Debug/CGAL_ImageIO-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.exp
4>  CGAL_ImageIO.vcxproj -> C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\bin\Debug\CGAL_ImageIO-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.dll
4>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
4>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
4>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
5>  moc_GraphicsViewNavigation.cpp
5>  moc_DemosMainWindow.cpp
5>  moc_GraphicsItem.cpp
5>  moc_GraphicsViewInput.cpp
5>  qrc_CGAL.cpp
5>  qrc_Input.cpp
5>  qrc_File.cpp
5>  qrc_Triangulation_2.cpp
5>  Génération de code en cours...
5>     Création de la bibliothèque C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Debug/CGAL_Qt5-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.lib et de l'objet C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Debug/CGAL_Qt5-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.exp
5>     Création de la bibliothèque C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Debug/CGAL_Qt5-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.lib et de l'objet C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Debug/CGAL_Qt5-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.exp
5>  CGAL_Qt5.vcxproj -> C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\bin\Debug\CGAL_Qt5-vc100-mt-gd-4.7.dll
5>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
5>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
5>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
6>------ Début de la génération : Projet : ALL_BUILD, Configuration : Debug Win32 ------
6>  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/CMakeLists.txt
6>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
========== Génération : 6 a réussi (succeed), 0 a échoué (failed), 0 mis à jour (updated), 0 a été ignoré (ignored)==========
```

I had the error message: impossible to open the file ALL_BUILD because it can be found.

I did the generation under release:

```css
1>------ Début de la génération (beginning of the generation) : Projet : ZERO_CHECK, Configuration : Release Win32 ------
1>  Checking Build System
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/src/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/src/CGAL/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/src/CGAL_Core/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/src/CGAL_ImageIO/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/src/CGAL_Qt5/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
2>------ Début de la génération : Projet : CGAL, Configuration : Release Win32 ------
2>  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/src/CGAL/CMakeLists.txt
2>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\src\CGAL\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
2>  all_files.cpp
2>     Création de la bibliothèque C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Release/CGAL-vc100-mt-4.7.lib et de l'objet C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Release/CGAL-vc100-mt-4.7.exp
2>  CGAL.vcxproj -> C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\bin\Release\CGAL-vc100-mt-4.7.dll
2>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
2>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
3>------ Début de la génération : Projet : CGAL_Core, Configuration : Release Win32 ------
4>------ Début de la génération : Projet : CGAL_ImageIO, Configuration : Release Win32 ------
5>------ Début de la génération : Projet : CGAL_Qt5, Configuration : Release Win32 ------
3>  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/src/CGAL_Core/CMakeLists.txt
3>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\src\CGAL_Core\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
5>  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/src/CGAL_Qt5/CMakeLists.txt
4>  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/src/CGAL_ImageIO/CMakeLists.txt
4>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\src\CGAL_ImageIO\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
5>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\src\CGAL_Qt5\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
3>  all_files.cpp
5>  Generating __/__/include/CGAL/Qt/moc_GraphicsViewNavigation.cpp
4>  all_files.cpp
5>  Generating __/__/include/CGAL/Qt/moc_DemosMainWindow.cpp
5>  Generating __/__/include/CGAL/Qt/moc_GraphicsItem.cpp
5>  Generating __/__/include/CGAL/Qt/moc_GraphicsViewInput.cpp
5>  Generating qrc_CGAL.cpp
5>  Generating qrc_Input.cpp
5>  Generating qrc_File.cpp
5>  Generating qrc_Triangulation_2.cpp
5>  all_files.cpp
3>     Création de la bibliothèque C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Release/CGAL_Core-vc100-mt-4.7.lib et de l'objet C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Release/CGAL_Core-vc100-mt-4.7.exp
3>  CGAL_Core.vcxproj -> C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\bin\Release\CGAL_Core-vc100-mt-4.7.dll
3>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
3>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
4>     Création de la bibliothèque C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Release/CGAL_ImageIO-vc100-mt-4.7.lib et de l'objet C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Release/CGAL_ImageIO-vc100-mt-4.7.exp
4>  CGAL_ImageIO.vcxproj -> C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\bin\Release\CGAL_ImageIO-vc100-mt-4.7.dll
4>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
4>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
5>  moc_GraphicsViewNavigation.cpp
5>  moc_DemosMainWindow.cpp
5>  moc_GraphicsItem.cpp
5>  moc_GraphicsViewInput.cpp
5>  qrc_CGAL.cpp
5>  qrc_Input.cpp
5>  qrc_File.cpp
5>  qrc_Triangulation_2.cpp
5>  Génération de code en cours...
5>     Création de la bibliothèque C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Release/CGAL_Qt5-vc100-mt-4.7.lib et de l'objet C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/build/lib/Release/CGAL_Qt5-vc100-mt-4.7.exp
5>  CGAL_Qt5.vcxproj -> C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\bin\Release\CGAL_Qt5-vc100-mt-4.7.dll
5>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
5>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
6>------ Début de la génération : Projet : ALL_BUILD, Configuration : Release Win32 ------
6>  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/CMakeLists.txt
6>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
========== Génération : 6 a réussi (succeed), 0 a échoué (failed), 0 mis à jour (updated), 0 a été ignoré (ignored) ==========
```

Same error message as in debug.

I put C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build\bin in my path.

Building an example:

I opened CMAKE-GUI and put C:/dev/CGAL-4.7/examples/Convex_hull_2 as a source and C:\dev\CGAL-4.7\build-example\Convex_hull_2 for where to build the binary.

First configuration:

```css
The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.40219.1
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.40219.1
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010 -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010 -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Build type: Release
USING CXXFLAGS = ' /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /fp:strict /fp:except- /wd4503 /bigobj /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG'
USING EXEFLAGS = ' /machine:X86 /INCREMENTAL:NO'
Targetting Visual Studio 10 2010
Target build enviroment supports auto-linking
Using VC10 compiler.
Generator uses intermediate configuration directory: $(Configuration)
Requested component: Core
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
Configuring done
```

Second configuration

```css
Build type: Release
USING CXXFLAGS = ' /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /fp:strict /fp:except- /wd4503 /bigobj /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG'
USING EXEFLAGS = ' /machine:X86 /INCREMENTAL:NO'
Targetting Visual Studio 10 2010
Target build enviroment supports auto-linking
Using VC10 compiler.
Generator uses intermediate configuration directory: $(Configuration)
Requested component: Core
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
Configuring done

Generating done.
```

WHen I run an example like convexhull 2 the exe file cannot be opened since boot_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_59.dll is missing.

Can you help me please?

Thank you for your time and help!

Best regards,

Jérémie

Comment: I can show you the output for the generation of the example if you want (no space to include it)!

Comment: Do you have `boot_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_59.dll` in your boost install? I no then you also need to compile it in debug. If yes then you should add the path to the directory containing this file in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have boost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_59.dll and I put C:\dev\boost_1_59_0\lib32-msvc-10.0 in my path. When I launch the exe file, there is no error pop up.  However the command prompt opened remains empty.

Comment: The example is probably waiting for input. Look at the code to see what's required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried to set up a different example that requires the same package that I need (mesh_3). However, in CMAKE-GUI it said that I need to define TBBROOT and/or TBB_ARCH_PLATFORM in the environment variables. So, I download TBB for windows and extract it in c/\dev\tbb44_20151115oss_win_0 and added TBBROOT=C:\dev\tbb44_20151115oss_win_0\tbb44_20151115oss\bin\ia32\ and TBB_ARCH_PLATFORM=ia32/vc10 to environment variables. FInally I added C:\dev\tbb44_20151115oss_win_0\tbb44_20151115oss\bin\ia32\vc10 to my path. But it doesn't fix the error message. Thanks again!

Comment: Ps: I tried to look what to put as an input for convex_hull but the code is like this:

Comment: `#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>`
`#include <CGAL/ch_graham_andrew.h>`
`typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;`
`typedef K::Point_2 Point_2;`
`int main()`
`{`
 `CGAL::set_ascii_mode(std::cin);`
  `CGAL::set_ascii_mode(std::cout);`
`std::istream_iterator< Point_2 >  in_start( std::cin );`
  `std::istream_iterator< Point_2 >  in_end;`
 `std::ostream_iterator< Point_2 >  out( std::cout, "\n" );`
 `CGAL::ch_graham_andrew( in_start, in_end, out );`
 `return 0;`  and I can't see any inputs.

Comment: I guess you have t learn first, what std::cin  is about. Have a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Comment: Thank your for the tutorial !

Comment: Everything is working now. Thank you all!